# are modules compatible with older versions in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios7

Once modules are turned on, we can start using them instead of the usual `#import` syntax, we simply use `@import` . Will it create compatibility issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules have no effect on the iOS compatibility. It's an IDE / compiler feature that doesn't require anything new from iOS.

Comment: so if i use @import syntax insted of #import in my project , will it work in older versions too ??

Comment: Yes, your app will work with older iOS versions. The use of modules doesn't change anything there. (However, your source code will no longer compile with older versions of XCode.)